VirtualBox is unable to open my External Drive
I've recently installed VirtualBox in my Arch machine to do a college course since they require us to use it, I've been using QEMU as my KVM emulator, but they insist on using VBox.
After installing it I added the Oracle Extension Pack and added my user to the "vboxuser" group, after that, I decided to plug in my External SSD to install and manage the Virtual Machines from there, however, at the time of creating a new Virtual Machine I cannot seem to read the drive in question, it does not appear in the explorer whatsoever, what irritates me is that QEMU is able to do so, and I've managed to run multiple virtual machines out of that.
In fact, VBox recognizes it, by doing the command VBoxManage list usbhost it lists the following.
Port:               1
USB version/speed:  3/Super
Manufacturer:       NetacPortableSSD
Product:            NetacPortableSSD
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-2//device:/dev/vboxusb/004/002
Current State:      Busy

I've tried looking information for it, but nothing seems to really match my problem, I also tried reinstalling the Oracle Extension Pack to no avail.
There is no error logs, and journalctl doesn't say anything about it. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Host OS? What usage scenario you're asking about?

Host is Arch Linux, I'm using the latest version of the kernel, I made sure to install the correct modules. What I'm trying to achieve here is to access the contents of the external drive with VirtualBox to be able to locate the ISO files stored inside there as well as storing virtual machines there.

So you need to [edit] the question and describe exactly 1) how are you trying to do those things you mentioned in the comment and 2) what happens when you try. This, of course, alongside adding the information you just gave. Requested info should always be edited into the question, not just comments. AFAIK, Virtualbox is NOT available as a SNAP package or Flatpak package for which confinement issues could prevent access to files not in your userspace.

I've purely tried trying to find any sort of error log, but as described above, I didn't find anything.

We don't need any error log unless there's an error explicitly showing somewhere in the process. What we need to know in order to understand the problem is exactly what I asked above. You need to clarify WHAT happens.

In a nutshell, if the drive is accessible in the host OS, it's accessible for Virtualbox.

See that's the problem, the drive is completely accessible in the host OS, but unreadable for VirtualBox even after allowing it to have access. I said above that VirtualBox recognizes the drive, but for some reason at the moment of looking up files of the drive inside VirtualBox, I cannot enter it, whatsoever.

Clarification be needed I think the problem is already explained, I will clarify it as much as I can, but it's obvious what I'm trying to solve here.

The file manger Virtualbox opens when, for example, you're about to select the location for a new VM and/or choose a live/installation ISO, is the EXACT same as the host OS'. The external drive will be in the exact same mount point, likely under  /mediaor /mnt. what exactly do you see different? or you see the same but can't select location/files? This is the needed clarification, not you repeating "it's unreadable". And what do you mean by "allowing it to have access"? You don't do such thing unless you want to use it as a shared folder. That being the case you do it later.

I do not see anything, as much as I'd like to explain myself further, it's just that VirtualBox's file manager doesn't list the drive, trying the direct path to the drive using /media also returns nothing, saying the location isn't available. By allowing it to have access I meant the process to let VirtualBox enumerate the host USB devices, such as mouse, keyboard and in my case external drives, this was obviously done by adding my user to the vboxuser group and it worked as expected, VirtualBox could see all of my USB devices, but can't access the external drive in the File Manager.

Did you or did you not set the external drive as a shared drive? If you want to access it for saving the VMs files and/or get the ISOs from it, you don't add it as a shared drive...

I ended up reinstalling VirtualBox this time following the official Arch manual and this time somehow it was able to read the drive in question.

As the actual cause for the described problems was not and will not be found, I'm voting to close this.


Select a VM
Go into Settings
Select Storage
To the right of the text Storage Devices there are tiny-tiny icons with + characters.
Click the left one for "Add Optical device" or the right one for "Add hardisk"
a selector appears that allows to point out a vmdk, or ISO (or whatever supported).
The "devices" you have attached will appear when you start the VM

NOTE: You may chose to create one or more vmdk-files on the external drive.
Oracle VBox 7.0.22
